# Cannot extract table using Selenium and BS despite seeing it in the HTML using inspect

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have a website that has a dynamic table, which simply does not show up when I try to use combos of Selenium and BS.

I have looked at code in several answers, but none of it works.

Do you have any bulletproof code that will extract tables, no matter how dynamic the webpage is?

Here is my (unsuccessful) attempt :

```
# Configure Selenium options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run in headless mode
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(url)

# Get the full page source
page_source = driver.page_source

# Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

# Find all tables using class name or attribute value
tables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'table1'})

print(tables)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Prior to that also tried using requests.get with headers equal to:

```
   

     header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}
```

Then I also tried adding sleep or time to wait for content to load... but nada.

The table is nested here in the html:

```
<div class="rightContainer" style="width:730px">
        <div id="master" class="mainContent Small" style="width:730px">
            <div class="greyContainerBtm">
                <div class="greyContainerBody">
                    <div class="freeTextArea">
                        <img class="printObj" src="/images/logo.gif" style="display:none">
                        <h2 class="printObj" style="display:none">Foreign Currency Fixed Deposit Rates</h2>
                        <b>(As at&nbsp;<span id="datetime">20-JUN-2023  10:30 a.m.</span>)</b>
                        <br><br><span>The rates shown here are indicative only and are subject to change without prior notice.</span>
                        <div class="mainContentArea" style="width:700px">
                            <br>
                            <h2 class="pageTitle">Board Rates</h2><br><h2 class="printObj" style="display:none">Board Rates</h2><br><table class="table1">
                                 
                                
                                <tbody><tr> 
                                    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2" id="hd1_1" class="txt_acc_type valignC" style="width: 100px;">Currency </th>
                                    <th colspan="7" class="txt_deposit_term alignC valignC">Rate (% p.a.)</th>
                                </tr>              
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="txt_overnight highlight alignR" id="hd1_2" style="width: 70px;">Minimum (Equivalent) Personal / Corporate</td>
                                    <td class="txt_24h highlight alignR" id="hd1_3" style="width: 60px;">1 week</td>
                                    <td class="txt_24h highlight alignR" id="hd1_4">1 month</td>
                                    <td class="txt_24h highlight alignR" id="hd1_5">2 months</td>
                                    <td class="txt_24h highlight alignR" id="hd1_6">3 months</td>
                                    <td class="txt_24h highlight alignR" id="hd1_7">6 months</td>
                                    <td class="txt_24h highlight alignR" id="hd1_8">12 months</td>
                                </tr>
                                        
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Australian Dollar</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>AUD</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">USD10K/20K</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.6400</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.8000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.0600</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.2800</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.4900</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.9300</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Canadian Dollar</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>CAD</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">USD10K/20K</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.2200</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.2700</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.4600</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.6500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.8500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.2200</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Swiss Franc</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>CHF</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">USD10K/20K</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.0700</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.2300</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.2300</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.3200</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.4200</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.6600</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Renminbi</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>CNY</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">USD10K/20K</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.2500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.2000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.3000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.7000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.8000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">2.0000</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Euro</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>EUR</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">USD10K/20K</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">2.8000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">2.9200</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.0300</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.1400</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.3900</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.5900</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Pound Sterling</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>GBP</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">USD10K/20K</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.0200</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.2700</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.4000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.5300</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.8600</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.2400</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Hong Kong Dollar</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>HKD</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">USD10K/20K</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.6300</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.6400</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.6400</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.6400</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.6600</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.7500</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Japanese Yen</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>JPY</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">USD10K/20K</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.0000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.0000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.0000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.0000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.0000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.0000</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>New Zealand Dollar</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>NZD</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">USD10K/20K</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.8500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.9500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.1900</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.3900</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.5500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.8500</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>United States Dollar</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>USD</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">USD10K/20K</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.1700</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.2500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.7200</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.9000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.0000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.0400</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                            </tbody></table>
                            <br> <br>
                            <h2 class="pageTitle">Tier Rates </h2><br><h2 class="printObj" style="display:none">Tier Rates </h2><br><table class="table2">
                                
                                
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="txt_acc_type valignC" id="hd1_1" width="100">Currency </th>
                                    <th colspan="7" class="txt_deposit_term alignC valignC">Rate (% p.a.)</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="txt_overnight highlight alignR" id="hd1_2" width="70">Minimum </td>
                                    <td class="txt_24h highlight alignR" id="hd1_3" width="60">1 week</td>
                                    <td class="txt_24h highlight alignR" id="hd1_3" width="60">1 month</td>
                                    <td class="txt_24h highlight alignR" id="hd1_3" width="60">2 months</td>
                                    <td class="txt_24h highlight alignR" id="hd1_3" width="60">3 months</td>
                                    <td class="txt_24h highlight alignR" id="hd1_3" width="60">6 months</td>
                                    <td class="txt_24h highlight alignR" id="hd1_3" width="60">12 months</td>
                                </tr>
                                        
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Australian Dollar</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>AUD</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">100,000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.7700</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.9300</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.1900</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.4100</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.6200</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.0600</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Canadian Dollar</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>CAD</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">100,000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.3500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.4000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.5900</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.7800</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.9800</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.3500</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Swiss Franc</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>CHF</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">100,000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.2000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.3600</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.3600</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.4500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.5500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.7900</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Renminbi</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>CNY</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">500,000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.3000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.5000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">1.6000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">2.0000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">2.1000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">2.3000</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Euro</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>EUR</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">100,000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">2.9300</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.0500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.1600</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.2700</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.5200</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">3.7200</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Pound Sterling</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>GBP</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">50,000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.1500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.4000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.5300</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.6600</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.9900</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.3700</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Hong Kong Dollar</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>HKD</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">500,000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.7600</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.7700</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.7700</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.7700</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.7900</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.8800</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>Japanese Yen</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>JPY</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">10,000,000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.0000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.0000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.0000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.0000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.0000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">0.0000</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>New Zealand Dollar</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>NZD</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">100,000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.9800</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.0800</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.3200</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.5200</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.6800</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.9800</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                                        <tr class="data">
                                            <td class="align"><b>United States Dollar</b></td>
                                            <td class="align"><b>USD</b></td>  
                                            <td class="alignR">100,000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.3000</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.3800</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">4.8500</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.0300</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.1300</td>
                                            <td class="alignR">5.1700</td>
                                        </tr>       
                                            
                            </tbody></table>
                            <br><br><br> 
                            <div style="width:700px">
                                <b>Notes:</b><br>For fixed deposit amount of SGD500,000 equivalent or over, please contact us for the applicable prevailing interest rate. 
                            </div>
                            <br>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div> '''
enter code here
```

Comment: Mind sharing the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see is loaded from different URL (`<iframe>`):

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.hkbea.com/jsp/sg/beasg_rate_fcfdr.jsp?fontSize=-1'

df1, df2 = pd.read_html(url)
print(df1)
print('-'*80)
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
                                     Currency                 Rate (% p.a.)                                                                                                                  
                                     Currency Currency.1 Unnamed: 2_level_1 Unnamed: 3_level_1 Unnamed: 4_level_1 Unnamed: 5_level_1 Unnamed: 6_level_1 Unnamed: 7_level_1 Unnamed: 8_level_1
0   Minimum (Equivalent) Personal / Corporate     1 week            1 month           2 months           3 months           6 months          12 months                NaN                NaN
1                           Australian Dollar        AUD         USD10K/20K             3.6400             3.8000             4.0600             4.2800               4.49               4.93
2                             Canadian Dollar        CAD         USD10K/20K             4.2200             4.2700             4.4600             4.6500               4.85               5.22
3                                 Swiss Franc        CHF         USD10K/20K             1.0700             1.2300             1.2300             1.3200               1.42               1.66
4                                    Renminbi        CNY         USD10K/20K             0.2500             1.2000             1.3000             1.7000               1.80               2.00
5                                        Euro        EUR         USD10K/20K             2.8000             2.9200             3.0300             3.1400               3.39               3.59
6                              Pound Sterling        GBP         USD10K/20K             4.0200             4.2700             4.4000             4.5300               4.86               5.24
7                            Hong Kong Dollar        HKD         USD10K/20K             4.6300             4.6400             4.6400             4.6400               4.66               4.75
8                                Japanese Yen        JPY         USD10K/20K             0.0000             0.0000             0.0000             0.0000               0.00               0.00
9                          New Zealand Dollar        NZD         USD10K/20K             4.8500             4.9500             5.1900             5.3900               5.55               5.85
10                       United States Dollar        USD         USD10K/20K             4.1700             4.2500             4.7200             4.9000               5.00               5.04
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Currency                 Rate (% p.a.)                                                                                                                  
                Currency Currency.1 Unnamed: 2_level_1 Unnamed: 3_level_1 Unnamed: 4_level_1 Unnamed: 5_level_1 Unnamed: 6_level_1 Unnamed: 7_level_1 Unnamed: 8_level_1
0                Minimum     1 week            1 month           2 months           3 months           6 months          12 months                NaN                NaN
1      Australian Dollar        AUD             100000             3.7700             3.9300             4.1900             4.4100               4.62               5.06
2        Canadian Dollar        CAD             100000             4.3500             4.4000             4.5900             4.7800               4.98               5.35
3            Swiss Franc        CHF             100000             1.2000             1.3600             1.3600             1.4500               1.55               1.79
4               Renminbi        CNY             500000             0.3000             1.5000             1.6000             2.0000               2.10               2.30
5                   Euro        EUR             100000             2.9300             3.0500             3.1600             3.2700               3.52               3.72
6         Pound Sterling        GBP              50000             4.1500             4.4000             4.5300             4.6600               4.99               5.37
7       Hong Kong Dollar        HKD             500000             4.7600             4.7700             4.7700             4.7700               4.79               4.88
8           Japanese Yen        JPY           10000000             0.0000             0.0000             0.0000             0.0000               0.00               0.00
9     New Zealand Dollar        NZD             100000             4.9800             5.0800             5.3200             5.5200               5.68               5.98
10  United States Dollar        USD             100000             4.3000             4.3800             4.8500             5.0300               5.13               5.17
```

Comment: So brilliant and simple! How did  you find out this URL? Is there any resouce where I can lear to solve my next requests SO EASILY?

Comment: @ClaRosie When you open Web Developer Tools and inspect the HTML tags you will see that the tables are placed under the `<iframe>`. IFrames load their contents from their src attribute. So that's the URL I'm scraping from.

Comment: Thank you Andrej! Will read into it now :-)

Comment: Btw I've just posted a new question ON THIS SAME URL... the pain! If you could help me would really appreciate it!

Comment: @ClaRosie If this answer solved your question, consider to accept it (there is V mark under the upvotes buttons).